# RangeObsevableCollection in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm working on a C#/WPF application.In one of the xaml screens, I've a windows datagrid and I'm binding my custome listview collection to it.
This listview collection(i.e. MyCollection) contains prices for various products.The collection is of type MyProduct:

```
public class MyProduct
{
public Int32 Id {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
public Decimal Price {get;set;} 
}
```

Users can edit the prices in the grid and save them back to the database.
I need to update only those prices which user modified in the UI.

I tried using delegate like below:

```
MyCollection.CollectionChanged += System.Specialized.NotifiyCollectionChangedEventHandler(myMethod);
```

But this event is not getting triggered somehow and hence myMethod is not getting invoked.How do I fix this please?

Is there any other way of achieving this?

Thanks.

Comment: What is `RangeObsevableCollection`? It isn't a built-in .NET collection type. Also, what is the exact type of `MyCollection`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on line where you subscribe to `CollectionChanged` event, i am gonna assume that you are using `ObservableCollection`. Event is not getting fired because collection isn't changed when you edit one of it's items. Event is raised when you add or delete but not if you change data in you `MyProduct` item. 
For example:

```
ObservableCollection<MyProduct> MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyProduct>();
MyCollection.Add(new MyProduct()); //Event is raised, becouse you changed collection
MyCollection.First().Id = 1; //Event is not raised, collection is same, nothing changed
```

So, you need to implement your own mechanism if you wanna get notified about changes within collection item.